# Wishing to fire code only when background timer reaches threshold not every min?

Tags: c#, linq, timer, backgroundworker

I am trying to send an email every 3 or 5 mins before an appointment time but some reason the code is firing every second I only want it to fire the alloted time before the timer reaches the threashold but I cannot acheive it. And would also make it easier to debug.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
   Timer timer = new Timer();
   worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
   timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
   timer.Interval = (1000) * (2);
   timer.Enabled = true;
   timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)  {
   if (!worker.IsBusy)
      worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

 private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)  {
    //whatever You want the background thread to do...
    doReminders(3);
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Does the reminders.
 /// sends out reminders based on the amount of minuties before a meeting
 /// </summary>
 protected void doReminders(int reminder)  {
    try  {
       List<ApertureDal.Appointment> _appointments = _dal.GetAppointmentsByReminderLength(reminder);

       _appointments.ForEach(x => {
           _dal.sendAppointmentEmails(x.ID, x.emailAddress, x.TimeCode, x.emailAddress, new Guid(Constants.calenderEmail), x.CustomerFirstName, x.CustomerLastName, x.managerName, x.preferedContactNumber, x.emailAddress, x.Start, x.End, x.managerId);
            });
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

**Edit to show the GetAppointments Function**

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets the appointments.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="reminderLength">Length of the reminder.</param>
 /// <returns></returns>
 public List<Appointment> GetAppointmentsByReminderLength(int reminderLength)
    {
        List<Appointment> list = new List<Appointment>();

        try
        {
            var q = from a in apertureNetEntities.Appointments //.Where(a => a.Start.Value.AddMinutes(-reminderLength) <= DateTime.Now)
                    select a;

            list = q.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            string inner = string.Empty;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            }
            logger.Error("Error in List<Appointment> function GetAppointmentsByReminderLength " + ex.ToString() + " " + inner);
            return null;
        }

        return list;
  }
```

**Edit** 
At present its sending me 98 emails even though i the db their is only one record which i tested.

Comment: I think the problem lies in _dal.GetAppointmentsByReminderLength(reminder) that may be returnung appointments that are not the soon.

Comment: @dryman I have made an edit to the quesiton to show that GetAppointmentsByReminderLength

Comment: GetAppointmentsByReminderLength returns all Appointments regardless if they are due or not because the LINQ Where is commented. It is quite clear that it will send all appointments every 2 seconds like this. But what is the wanted behaviour? If it should send all apointments every 3 minutes change timer.Interval and if you want to check every 2 seconds and send only due appointments you should uncomment the LING Where and use it to filter the appointments to send.

Comment: @dryman i had that out for testing to see if it got fired at least  the expected beavhiour is say they put in a reminder for 30 mins before then it should fire the email but obv i need to have it their that at the ticks to to only fire x minutes

Comment: @dryman at present even with that in i have only one record it was sending me 98 email when its only ment to send me 1 even though i have only one record in the db

Comment: Do you flag the appointment after sending the email? If you want only one email per appoinment you should have a flag that is set after sending und examined before sending it again. This way when the appointment is due it will be sent one time, the flag set, after 2 secondes the appointment is still due but you know from the flag that it has already been sent.

Comment: @dryman the problem is i have the send appointment email in a sperate dll how would i return that to the main aspx.cs page to check on it can you show a example and ill set as the answers thanks for your help

Comment: I do not have enough information on your software nor how ASP works I'm afraid. I don't know where apertureNetEntities are coming from or what happens in _dal.sendAppointmentEmails. The thing is that in sendAppointmentEmails or afterwards you have to change the entity in your database and load the change (some bool) in your GetAppointmentsByReminderLength to check. I don't know how to do this in detail.

Comment: @dryman thanks for your help was wanting to give you ur kudos mate

Comment: You're welcome. I will write a short answer so you can close this if you want.

Comment: @dryman yes please as like to give kudos sorry if my spelling is bad there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

The problem is that in this code there is no recognition whether the email has already been sent or not. So if an appointment is due there is an email generated and sent. 2 seconds after that it is checked again and still the appoinment is due so it will send an email again over and over.

There needs to be some bool in your appoinment that you set true in or after _dal.sendAppointmentEmails and that is read in _dal.GetAppointmentsByReminderLength and then checked. If the appoinment has already been set to true you don't have to send an email if it is still false you send the email and set the bool to true and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the timer interval to `(1000) * (2)` - that is - two seconds, so the timer event is fired every 2 seconds.

Comment: Yes I agree that it is their as well but how would I set it for every 30 mins x and then make sure its the apointment time.

Comment: You will need to create a `boolean` flag variable that you set when you send the email.  Each time the timer fires you should check if the flag is set, and not send the email if it is.